# Client side custom Validation for date range in mvc4

Tags: c#, jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

i am trying to validate a age to be above 18 year this is working on server side validation but it is not working in client side and i have no idea how to do it.
i saw articles but it didn't work.

1. i implemented logic in server side C#.
2. do i need to Implement same logic in Client side jQuery/JavaScript too.

my back-end code is

```
  public class ValidateAge : ValidationAttribute
{
    public ValidateAge( params string[] propertyNames)
    {
        this.PropertyNames = propertyNames;
    }


    public string[] PropertyNames { get; private set; }
    public int MinLength { get; private set; }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        if (DateTime.Compare(date, DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18)) == -1 || DateTime.Compare(date, DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18)) == 0)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        }


    }
}
```

in model it is this

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Date of birth is required.")]
  [ValidateAge(ErrorMessage="Age must be above 18.")]
  [DataType(DataType.Date)]
  public DateTime _Dob { get; set; }
```

it is validates model but doesnot show error message either serverside or client side ,i tried

```
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add but no one explained how to use it 
 i dont know how to make it work
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have to use remote validation.

Comment: can you tell me how does it work?

Comment: you can also use jqury function.This link for remote validation [http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d87001/remote-validation-in-mvc/](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d87001/remote-validation-in-mvc/).

Comment: i applied the same method i but now form is not even postingback ,
[HttpGet]
      [AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ValidateAge(String dt)
      {}
model 
  [Remote("ValidateAge","Account",ErrorMessage="Age must be above 18.")]

Comment: i figured out in network inspection it was working actually ,but problem is that i am using calander control when i use calender for input it does not work but when i use mannual input it works ,now the problem is i want it work with calender control.

Comment: Which calender's control are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91840/discussion-between-manish-sharma-and-br-bhardwaj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use remote validation also using this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d87001/remote-validation-in-mvc/.

`OR`

You can use this Javascript function for date validation on your button click.

```
 Date.prototype.age = function (at) {
        var value = new Date(this.getTime());
        var age = at.getFullYear() - value.getFullYear();
        value = value.setFullYear(at.getFullYear());
        if (at < value)--age;
        return age;
    };

var dob = new Date(Date.parse($(this).text()));

if (dob.age(new Date()) < 18) {
  $(this).text("Under 18");
}
else {
   $(this).text(" Over 18");
}
```

Comment: i used remote validation ,and called action using ajax on textbox blur event and it worked as it should work.

answer above had some errors and i was having hard time doing logic in javascript so i didnt go further.
problem included 
like comparing date ,and getting date from day ,month,and year jparamether ,then it was may be localisation/format problem.